# How send form content to other page in contact form 7 plugin

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

The plugin "Contact-Form-7: 3rd-Party Integration" shows an error. I need to send the form to another page without modifying send mail functionality.

Comment: What's the error? What have you tried?